# Joda time : Most recent week and month

Tags: jodatime

What would be the best way to get the start/end dates of most recent complete week and most recent complete month given the date.

I.E given the todays date, how to find out the week that just completed, same for month.

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution

```
    LocalDate today = new LocalDate()

    LocalDate lastWeek = today.minusWeeks(1)
    start= lastWeek .dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue().minusDays(1)
    end = lastWeek.dayOfWeek().withMaximumValue().minusDays(1)

    LocalDate lastMonth = today.minusMonths(1)
    timeStart = lastMonth.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue()
    timeEnd = lastMonth.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue()
```

Answer (score 4):

For a month it's easy - something like:

```
LocalDate endOfPreviousMonth = date.withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
```

For a week it's slightly trickier. You can do this:

```
LocalDate previousSunday = date.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY)
                               .minusDays(1);
```

... but it's not clear to me whether `withDayOfWeek` will always go to the *previous* Monday or the *closest* Monday. (It's something I'm going to figure out in Noda Time and give options...)

Instead, you could try this:

```
// Go back 1 day for Monday, 2 days for Tuesday etc
LocalDate previousSunday = date.minusDays(date.getDayOfWeek());
```

Once you've got the *end* of the completed week or month, you can get to the *start* easily enough:

```
LocalDate startOfPreviousMonth = endOfPreviousMonth.withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate startOfPreviousWeek = previousSunday.minusDays(6);
```

Comment: I believe that date.withDayOfWeek returns a LocalDate that has the same week-of-year as the current date, but the specified day-of-week. In some cases that may not be the same as either the previous, or the closest, like when going from a Monday to a Friday. JodaTime has three main date representations (Year-month-day), (year, week, day-of-week), and (year, day of year). withDayOfWeek is very confusing (and not very useful) if you only care about the common (year, month, day) representation. In the case of Monday in the ISO8601 system, it will always be the same day or previous Monday.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for that. It would be useful if the docs were rather clearer on this :) (By week-of-year do you mean week-of-week-year btw?)

Comment: I was just referencing the general concept of a numbered week of the year. To be specific it would be the week stored in the weekOfWeekyear field. As a result of this API, using `date.getDayofWeek` and `date.plusDays`/`date.minusdays` is the most reliable. Under ISO8601, `withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.XXXDay)` means `XXXDay` of the current week, if you define the week to start on Monday (not on Sunday). Since that is rather easy to forget and contrary to possible expectations, I'd advise avoiding it entirely unless your business domain is based on the ISO (year, week, dayofweek) model.

Comment: @Kevin: Right. Given that I'm porting Noda Time to .NET at the moment, that's well worth knowing. I was going to make the API "find next X" and "find previous X" (for day-of-week X) which is somewhat easier to get right.

Comment: As far as the implications on NodaTime, NodaTime currently favors the (year,month,day), providing support for reading the others, but not performing much math based on them. Since they are uncommon, emphasising them like JodaTime implicitly does tends to cause confusion. A function like WithWeekOfWeeKYear can easilly be implemented as an extention method, either by the end user who needs it, or by you, and stuck in a namespace for uncommon operations.

Comment: @Kevin: Yup. We're avoiding extension methods in general as they require .NET 3.5 (or hacks) and we're targeting 2.0. But aside from some special-casing operations as described before, I agree that we're downplaying them compared with Joda - I hadn't really thought of it like that before.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some research on the JODA time, here are the some useful results for reference.

```
 import org.joda.time.DateTime;
    import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants;
    import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
    import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
    import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

    public class JodaDemo {
        public static final String DATE_PATTERN = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter jf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_PATTERN);

        //get first & last day of relative year
        System.out.println(jf.print(new LocalDate().dayOfYear().withMinimumValue()));
        System.out.println(jf.print(new LocalDate().dayOfYear().withMaximumValue()));

        //get first & last day of month
        System.out.println(jf.print(new LocalDate().dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue()));
        System.out.println(jf.print(new LocalDate().dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue()));

        //get first & last day of current week
        System.out.println(jf.print(new LocalDate().dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue()));
        System.out.println(jf.print(new LocalDate().dayOfWeek().withMaximumValue()));
        //or
        System.out.println("=="+jf.print(new LocalDate().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY)));
        System.out.println("=="+jf.print(new LocalDate().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY)));

        //print todays date
        System.out.println(jf.print(DateTime.now()));

        // print 2 years before and after date
        System.out.println(jf.print(DateTime.now().minusYears(2)));
        System.out.println(jf.print(DateTime.now().plusYears(2)));

        // get first date of century era
        System.out.println(jf.print(DateTime.now().getCenturyOfEra()));
    }
    }
```