# How to build first and last of month as timestamp, with given timestamp?

Tags: java, date, coding-style, jodatime

Assuming a given `Timestamp timestamp`:

I am using Joda Time to build the first day of the month:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp);    
MutableDateTime firstOfMonth = dateTime.toMutableDateTime();
firstOfMonth.setDayOfMonth(1);
firstOfMonth.setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

and the last day of the month:

```
MutableDateTime lastOfMonth = firstOfMonth.toMutableDateTime();
lastOfMonth.addMonths(1);
lastOfMonth.addMillis(-1);
```

But I wondered that calculating `firstOfMonth` and `lastOfMonth` this needs so much code. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: This is fairly well covered (though not precisely this question) [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130948/joda-time-most-recent-week-and-month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/upgradeto120.html)

```
DateTime dt = ...
DateTime firstDayOfMonth = dt.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue();
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = dt.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
```

Comment: That looks promising - does it actually set it to the last millisecond of the month, or does it only update the day field?

Comment: As I understand it, only the respective property (in this case `dateOfMonth`) is set to the min/max value dependent on the DateTime. I cannot test it currently.